# Can this query be any faster?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have got the following query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM 
(  
    SELECT M.id, M.project_id, M.reply_toaddress as reply_toemailaddress, M.phone_no, M.subject,M.message, M.timestamp_received, M.done, M.postpone,  "mail" AS type, M.firstname, M.prefix, M.surname
    FROM messages M
    LEFT JOIN link_projects_mailboxes LPMB 
        ON M.mailbox_id = LPMB.mailbox_id
    WHERE M.main_message_id =0  
         AND LPMB.projects_id = 13  AND ( 0 OR  (M.done = 0 AND M.postpone = 0 ))  AND M.status = 0  
    GROUP BY M.id 
) M
UNION 
(
    SELECT C.id, C.project_id, C.reply_toemailaddress, C.phone_no, C.subject,C.message, C.timestamp_received, done, postpone, "call" AS type , C.firstname, C.prefix, C.surname
    FROM calls C
    WHERE 1 
         AND projects_id = 13  AND ( 0 OR  (C.done = 0 AND C.postpone = 0 ))  AND C.status = 0  
) 
) x ORDER BY  `timestamp_received`  asc  LIMIT 30
```

The problem is that this query is running on 700.000 rows with 19.2GB data. The query runs for about 3 minutes.

If I explain the query I recieve the following result:

[image]

Do you guys have any suggestions?

EDIT: Show Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mailbox_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `submessage_of` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `main_message_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Takes project from afasmssql_sync DB',
  `categorie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `call_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `to` text NOT NULL,
  `cc` text NOT NULL,
  `bcc` text NOT NULL,
  `message_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `bytes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `from` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `sender` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reply_toaddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reply_toemailaddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `prefix` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `emailaddress` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `house_no` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `house_no_add` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `message_plain` longtext NOT NULL,
  `message_stripped` longtext NOT NULL,
  `quality_status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `quality_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quality_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `done_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `done_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postpone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `manually` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp_received` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mailbox_id` (`mailbox_id`),
  KEY `submessage_of` (`submessage_of`),
  KEY `main_message_id` (`main_message_id`),
  KEY `subject` (`subject`),
  KEY `done` (`done`),
  KEY `postpone` (`postpone`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
  KEY `categorie_id` (`categorie_id`),
  KEY `call_id` (`call_id`),
  KEY `done_date` (`done_date`),
  KEY `timestamp_received` (`timestamp_received`),
  KEY `from` (`from`),
  KEY `reply_toemailaddress` (`reply_toemailaddress`),
  KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `message` (`message`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=685579 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `link_projects_mailboxes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `projects_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mailbox_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `projects_id` (`projects_id`,`mailbox_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=156 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

CREATE TABLE `calls` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `actionline_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `projects_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `project_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Takes project from afasmssql_sync DB',
  `categorie_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `call_direction` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order_location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `prefix` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `reply_toemailaddress` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `phone_no` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `house_no` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `house_no_add` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `street` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext NOT NULL,
  `done` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `done_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `done_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `postpone` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp_received` datetime NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mailbox_id` (`actionline_id`),
  KEY `subject` (`subject`),
  KEY `done` (`done`),
  KEY `postpone` (`postpone`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `project_id` (`project_id`),
  KEY `projects_id` (`projects_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `message` (`message`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8941 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

EDIT: EXPLAIN based on Strawberries answer:

[image]

Comment: Why there is a "where 1" ?

Comment: @dacrovinunghi That's a common placeholder to allow you to add additional `AND xxx` clauses dynamically. It's usually done as `WHERE 1=1`, but it's the same thing.

Comment: If you run the two subqueries by themselves, are they also slow? The problem could be due to removing duplicates from the `UNION`. If there aren't any duplicates, try using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: You haven't given the schema and many of the columns referenced by the query are not prefixed with the table alias so it's very hard to know exactly what is going on here. You've got a GROUP BY in the first subquery that I assume is to handle multiple rows from the LEFT JOIN table, but I can't tell why that table is even in the query because I don't know which columns are in which table.

Comment: Where do `main_message_id`, `projects_id`, `done` and `postpone` all come from

Comment: @Strawberry I added the aliases in the query

Comment: So you OUTER JOIN a table from which you select no columns? That makes no sense

Comment: Please add `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` for each of your tables to your question.

Comment: @Strawberry its used in the where clause

Comment: In which case it's an INNER JOIN, so write it as that

Comment: @WillemRenzema Added the tables

Comment: @Barmar there can be no duplicates here - the first query selects the literal "mail" as type, the second "call", so replacing `union` with `union all` is completely safe.

Comment: @Mureinik Thanks, I didn't notice that since it was scrolled far off to the right.

Comment: Please answer my question above: If you run the subqueries by themselves, are they slow? Is just one of them slow? As Strawberry said, you should use `INNER JOIN` if you don't need rows in the first table that have no matches in the second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, just to make things more readable, let's start with this query, and run the EXPLAIN on that instead...

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
  FROM
     ( SELECT M.id
            , M.project_id
            , M.reply_toaddress as reply_toemailaddress
            , M.phone_no
            , M.subject
            , M.message
            , M.timestamp_received
            , M.done
            , M.postpone
            , "mail" type
            , M.firstname
            , M.prefix
            , M.surname
         FROM messages M
         JOIN link_projects_mailboxes LPMB 
           ON LPMB.mailbox_id = M.mailbox_id 
        WHERE M.main_message_id = 0  
          AND LPMB.projects_id = 13  
          AND M.done = 0 
          AND M.postpone = 0 
          AND M.status = 0  
        UNION 
       SELECT C.id
            , C.project_id
            , C.reply_toemailaddress
            , C.phone_no
            , C.subject
            , C.message
            , C.timestamp_received
            , C.done
            , C.postpone
            , "call" type 
            , C.firstname
            , C.prefix
            , C.surname
         FROM calls C
        WHERE C.projects_id = 13  
          AND C.done = 0 
          AND C.postpone = 0 
          AND C.status = 0  
     ) x 
 ORDER 
    BY timestamp_received ASC
 LIMIT 30;
```

EXPLAIN for same:

```
+------+--------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
| id   | select_type  | table      | type | possible_keys    | key         | key_len | ref                 | rows  | Extra          |
+------+--------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL  | (NULL)           | (NULL)      | (NULL)  | (NULL)              |  218  | Using filesort |
+------+--------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
|    2 | DERIVED      | LPMB       | ref  | projects_id      | projects_id | 4       |                     |    1  | Using index    |
+------+--------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
|    2 | DERIVED      | M          | ref  | mailbox_id,      | mailbox_id  | 4       | ccc.LPMB.mailbox_id | 7,735 | Using where    |
|      |              |            |      | main_message_id, |             |         |                     |       |                |
|      |              |            |      | done,            |             |         |                     |       |                |
|      |              |            |      | postpone,        |             |         |                     |       |                |
|      |              |            |      | status           |             |         |                     |       |                |
+------+--------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
|    3 | UNION        | C          | ref  | done,            | done        | 1       |                     |     4 | Using where    |
|      |              |            |      | postpone,        |             |         |                     |       |                |
|      |              |            |      | status,          |             |         |                     |       |                |
|      |              |            |      | projects_id      |             |         |                     |       |                |
+------+--------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
|(NULL)| UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL  | (NULL)           | (NULL)      | (NULL)  | (NULL)              | (NULL)|                |
+------+--------------+------------+------+------------------+-------------+---------+---------------------+-------+----------------+
```

Comment: Added it to my question

Comment: @AgeDeO Is it still 3 minutes to run the query itself? Or is there any improvement?

Comment: @AgeDeO One addition to this new query to also try is to remove the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and see how it performs. Many times it is faster to do a separate COUNT(*)  query, rather than using SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS. See https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: @WillemRenzema it is around 20% faster. A lot considering it took about 3 minutes. I did not replace SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS yet

Comment: Is it deliberate that you don't join on project_id ?

Comment: Why was this the "accepted answer"?  I see nothing useful here.

Comment: Gosh, someone's grumpy. Guess who Santa disappointed this year ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the two inner `SELECTs` have no common rows, change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`.  That will save a dedup pass.  Run each of them to see which one is slower; then we can focus on it.

These 'composite' indexes may help it run significantly faster:

```
M:  INDEX(mailbox_id, message_id, done, postpone, status) -- in any order
calls:  INDEX(projects_id, done, postpone, status) -- in any order
```

If you did not need `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, this would be much faster:

```
( SELECT ... FROM M ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 30 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... FROM M ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT 30 )
ORDER BY ... LIMIT 30;   -- yes, repeated again
```

It would require suitable indexes, probably the ones suggested above, with `timestamp_received` added on the *end*.  And the virtually useless `JOIN LPMB` should be replaced by `AND EXISTS ( SELECT ... FROM LPMB ... )`

That `UNION`+`LIMIT` trick gets more complex, but still possible, if you are paginating with `OFFSET`.

Unrelated:

Get rid of indexes on individual flags; they are usually useless.

You should move from MyISAM to InnoDB.  `FULLTEXT` (slightly different) is available in later versions.

@dacrovinunghi - MySQL has no "bitmap" index type.

`WHERE 1` and `0 OR` come from dynamically building the `WHERE` clause, but not taking the time to keep it clean.  I prefer to build an array of clauses to be `AND'd`, then `implode` them.  Or, if none, avoid the `WHERE` all together.

It *may* be better to remove the "done" (etc) items from the table.  That would eliminate that part(s) of the `WHERE` and shrink the table, making it more compact and efficient.